# Notify on comment moderation

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-comments

This is the second time I see this happening.

I don't want to argue, or **flag**, on the quality and constructiveness of some other user's comments, but a few times I wrote a **comment** on a post and it disappeared (moderation???) without knowledge or notification. Personally, I won't think three to four times before *commenting*, and I think twice and re-read when *answering*.

I know that upvoted comments do not make rep score, but sometimes one likes to write a nice catch. Of course, in a plural context one must be **extremely** aware that borderline comments may have a negative impact on others.

Example 1: I can't exactly recall where, but once I did a *sarcastic* (!) comment about the Catholic Church. Not rude language, no unpronunciable wording, no offensive expressions, not accusation of anything. Just sarcasm. The question was something like "At immigration of country X, will they refuse me if I answer that I used drugs in the past?". I *sarcastically* commented something like "Cool, the Vatican City may choose to ban people who once happened to sleep with their unmarried partner".

When I came back a few days later, the comment disappeared. I <strike>learned</strike> thought that soft sarcarsm to the Church may be unwelcome. I would have made more sarcastic comments if I didn't see that comment disappearing. I passed on it and continued: trying to use less sarcasm on my future comments.

With this **example** I underline that I'm not interested in reinstating a comment or discussing any sarcasm-related policy.

Example 2: on [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/163550/39994) I made a comment about the name of Buffalo city, actually I cited one of the most strange pearls of the English language: [`Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo) (the comment didn't have the link for purpose of mystery). It worked as people started to upvote. And I was happy with it.

Now that I went checking for votes, it is disappeared. Without a reason. Okay that it is not constructive (!), but maybe was just adding some pleasure to the conversation. And I do understand that humour is particularly subjective and must be used with caution in a multicultural context.

## But

It would be nice to inform/warn the user when a comment is moderated.

Con: some people may start long arguments, or flames, with Meta or moderators about "why did you delete my innocent comment?". Can be a headache to the staff.

Pro: one can stop from be used to *bad behaviour* long before it's too late for their account not to be suspended. I.e. one "learns" early from innocent mistakes.

Comment: Also note that the official view is that [comments should not expect to be permanent](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work) on stackexchange.

Comment: Hilariously I wrote that as an answer and it got autoconverted to a trivial comment ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did delete the 8 x city name comment, as useless, filling space but not adding anything to the discussion. Yes, I did see it was getting upvotes, but I did not feel that upvotes were given for the quality of the comment but for the fun of it, which is not a reason to keep a comment.

We are not a site for funny posts.

I do remember your Vatican comment and felt it was way off topic, not acceptable at all. Not bad enough to take action against you in a comment.

It was not because of the actual religion in this case, I would have deleted any comment which made fun of any religion if I saw it, or if pointed to it by users. (But Roman Catholic and sex is a very sensitive area, so most comments would have been out of line on that.)

On travel we have a relatively light hand with comments, other sites only allow comments to ask for extra details about the question. (I bet there are also sites which do not clean up the comments, so I guess we are somewhere in the middle.)

Comments are likely to disappear, without warning and without letting you know about it. It has happened to all of us, mods included.

We will only contact a user about comments if they are making very many very bad comments.
So be glad we did not see the need to contact you.

Answer (score 1):

> It would be nice to inform/warn the user when a comment is moderated.

The feature request was asked on Meta.SE, and it got declined: [Notify user when their comment is removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187985/178179).

Overall, SE [isn't](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209694/178179) into sending notifications when some content gets removed.